# Demonstrate a VM Escape

Tags: windows, linux, virtualization, metasploit, kali-linux

I have to demonstrate a VM Escape for a project. After some light research, I have found a vulnerability CVE-2014-0983 "Oracle VirtualBox 3D Acceleration Multiple Memory Corruption Vulnerabilities". The [Rapid7 website](https://www.rapid7.com/db/modules/exploit/windows/local/virtual_box_opengl_escape) shows that an exploit for metasploit is available to trigger this vulnerability.

What is the best way of running the exploit, provided I want the attack to seem remote? (I am using a different PC to act as a remote attacker) The exploit is said to be tested on a Windows 7 host running VirtualBox 4.3.6, but doesn't mention which Operating System is running on the virtual box.

Also are there any  more ways to demonstrate a VM Escape? (I am not skilled enough to actually write VM Escape code)

Comment: I would guess it works with either a Linux or Windows guest OS, but you will have to test. VM escape isn't really a remote vuln, but you can simulate it by connecting remotely to the guest over SSH or RDP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VM escapes are typically local exploits in that they already need native code execution capabilities to talk to local virtual devices of the guest.

I believe the most convincing way would be to chain this together with a remote exploit, such as one for a browser. Open a Meterpreter session via the browser exploit, then you can use any local exploit from remote to perform privilege escalation or even VM escape. This tutorial summarizes the commands pretty well:

https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/privilege-escalation/

Please note that CVE-2014-0983 is a memory corruption exploit, so you have to set up your test environment to precisely match the exploit target ("VirtualBox 4.3.6 / Windows 7 SP1 / 64 bits").